# What does it mean if get_ident() returns the same value?

Tags: python, multithreading

If `get_ident()` returns the same value during the execution of a program, does that mean the thread is the same thread, or is it possible that the thread was restarted but got the same identifier as a previous thread?

If it is possible, how likely is it - pretty likely?

I ask because I expected a particular Thread subclass to be killed and restarted multiple times during a program, and only one instance of that subclass running as a thread at a time. But, I made those threads log their thread id returned by `get_ident()` occasionally, and I saw that it was pretty common for some ids to re-occur, even after a different id was logged after the first occurrence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it possible that the thread was restarted but got the same identifier as a previous thread?

Yep, it seems so. From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/thread.html#thread.get_ident):

> Thread identifiers may be recycled when a thread exits and another thread is created.

As for how common it is, it probably varies depending on the OS and the Python implementation, but I expect it to be a pretty frequent occurrence.